# Jackson serialize java composition to json

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jackson

I need some help in re-factoring my java response to the client.
so this is my current response which is serialized with jackson2 and works fine.

```
public class PermissionResponse {
  @JsonProperty
  private Long id;

  @JsonProperty
  private String name;

  @JsonProperty
  private Long actionId;

  @JsonProperty
  private String actionName;

  @JsonProperty
  private Long resourceId;

  @JsonProperty
  private String resourceName;

  @JsonProperty
  private Long environmentId;

  @JsonProperty
  private String environmentName;

  ...
}
```

but instead of passing setting

```
@JsonProperty
private String actionName;

@JsonProperty
private Long actionId;
```

I would like to have the action entity (containing those two fields - `actionName/name` and `actionId/id`). Something like:

```
@JsonProperty
private Action action;
```

Can someone point me to the right direction because I cannot find what I need here. Thanks

Comment: Don't need all those @JsonProperty annotations if your PermissionResponse object has getters and setters. Your nested Action object should get serialized automatically tool. What problem are you running into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no expert with Jackson, but I assume that as long as you can serialise the Action class, Jackson (like GSON) will serialise it anywhere.

In GSON this would be done in the following

```
public class PermissionResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Action action;
    private Long resourceId;
    private String resourceName;
    private Long environmentId;
    private String environmentName;
}

public class Action {

    private Long id;
    private String name
}
```

You should probably even make classes for both Resource and Environment eg:

```
public class PermissionResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Action action;
    private Resource resource;
    private Environment environment;
}

public class Action {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public class Resource {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public class Environment {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

The above examples, are compatible with GSON, so you will just have to try them with Jackson, how ever I'm sure once you have put in all the correct annotations they will work just fine.

EDIT: Going even further, you could create a Common class eg:

```
public class Permission {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public class PermissionResponse extends Permission {

    private Action action;
    private Resource resource;
    private Environment environment;
}

public class Action extends Permission {

}

public class Resource extends Permission {

}

public class Environment extends Permission {

}
```

and if you're not planning on adding anything else to Action, Resource or Environment, don't have those classes eg:

```
public class Permission {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

public class PermissionResponse extends Permission {

    private Permission action;
    private Permission resource;
    private Permission environment;
}
```

Obviously the above uses less code, however you lose the ability to know what type a Permission is (unless you know before you get the Object).